# Compute (or approximate) the sum of positive eigenvalues of a pre-distance matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

A pre-distance matrix is a real symmetric matrix with zero diagonal and nonnegative entries.

Let $M \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ be a pre-distance matrix and we want to compute the sum of its positive eigenvalues. In general, computing the sum of positive eigenvalues is as hard as computing all eigenvalues, i.e., eigendecomposition.

I am just wondering for such a special matrix, is there any way to (approximately) compute the quantity? Thanks in advance!

---

For example, when $n = 3$, suppose $M = \begin{pmatrix}
   0 & a & b \\
   a & 0 & c \\
   b & c & 0 \\
  \end{pmatrix}$,
then $$\operatorname{det}(M - \lambda I) = 
  \begin{vmatrix}
   -\lambda & a & b \\
   a & -\lambda & c \\
   b & c & -\lambda \\
  \end{vmatrix}
  = -\lambda^3 + (a^2 + b^2 + c^2) \lambda + 2 abc.$$

Thus, we may make use of, e.g., the trigonometric solution, to compute the roots.

Comment: It's desperate to look for the use of explicit formulas for the roots above degree 4 (there are none !) and even with degree 4, they are awfully complicated. More generaly using det(A_\lambda I) for computing eigenvalues is not the good way. If the dimensions of your matrices are large, you have to learn whole chapters of **numerical linear algebra** with algorithms such as the "divide and conquer" method or the "QR method"

Comment: I guess it depends on how "approximately" you want it. Note that $Tr(A^2)=\sum\lambda^2_i$, which can give you an bound on $\sum |\lambda_i|$.